# Rails + Slim Source Output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml, slim-lang

I've searched, and cannot find anything, maybe I'm searching for the wrong information because it seems this should be mentioned somewhere. Basically I have a question about the Slim Template Engine.

When using Slim, when I view the source code output from the browser, it is not nested properly and looks unprofessional, unlike HAML, which nests the tags properly. I am not sure if I am doing something incorrectly or not, if I am, please point me in the correct direction because I really love Slim, but unfortunately the source output is a deal breaker for me. I have my example codes and outputs below for both Slim and HAML.

I am unsure if it is relevant, as I am still quite new to Rails, but the specifications of my development machine are as follows:

```
*Fedora 18 x86_64
*Apache 2.4.4
*Ruby 2.0.0p195
*Rails 3.2.13

The Gem Versions for HAML and Slim:
haml (4.0.3)
haml-rails (0.4)
slim (2.0.0)
slim-rails (2.0.1)

*Apache configuration is set to: RailsEnv development
```

**Slim**

app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:

```
doctype html
html

    head
        title Test Website
        = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
        = javascript_include_tag "application"
        = csrf_meta_tags

    body
        = yield
```

Source Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test Website</title><link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script><meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="EFA1Dzi1D1DY4GVBlAJ+IIyhm7ZvYch8t5v2a6cj42k=" name="csrf-token" /></head><body><h1>Home#index</h1><p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.slim</p></body></html>
```

**HAML**

app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:

```
!!!
%html

    %head
        %title Test Website
        = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
        = javascript_include_tag "application"
        = csrf_meta_tags

    %body
        =yield
```

Source Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Website</title>
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="RmxaPGwJapEf16Uw8ApQG0CpCHtr4My4aD8UO9w80dY=" name="csrf-token" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Home#index</h1>
    <p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.haml</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing really wrong with the output, Slim is just compressing it for maximum performance. The browser doesn't care how it looks, as long as it works.

However during development it's understandable you may want a more readable version for debugging purposes.

You can [configure Slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#configuring-slim) to produce pretty output like so:

```rb
# Indent html for pretty debugging and do not sort attributes
Slim::Engine.set_default_options :pretty => true, :sort_attrs => false
```

Just put it in `config/environments/development.rb` for example and you're set.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! Exactly what I was looking for!